# Замена строк, удаление и смещение строк в текстовом файле

Tags: java

**Дано:** текстовый файл с содержимым в виде:

```
строка1
строка2
строка3
строка4
...
```

**Задача1:** заменить определенную строку файла на другой текст (в данном случае на текст из заданного параметра программы).

**Задача2:** удалить определенную строку (например вторую) и поднять остальные строки так, чтобы не было пустой строки, т.е. результат должен быть:

```
строка1
строка3
строка4
...
```

**Мой путь решения:**

- считал строки в лист;
- далее в зависимости от задачи заменял одну строку листа на текст из параметров программы или удалял строку из него;
- на следующем этапе записываю строки листа в стрингу, а стрингу в файл:

  ```
    Path path = Paths.get(file);
    String allLines = "";
    for (String s: lines) {
        allLines += s + "\n";
    }
    Files.writeString(path, allLines);
  ```

**Проблема: И здесь я натыкаюсь на неожиданное для меня явление: вся стринга записывается в файл в одну строку, а не построчно, как планировалось.**

**Вопросы: Почему запись в файл происходит в одну строку? Как добиться нужного результата и есть ли другие способы замены части текста файла на другой и удаление определенной строки с последующим смещением остальных строк? Спасибо!**

*P.S. решил эту задачу через BufferedWriter'ы:*

```
switch (args[0]) {
   case "-u":
      try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
          for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
         if (lines.get(i).substring(0, 8).trim().equals(args[1]) ||
             lines.get(i).substring(0, lines.get(i).indexOf(" ")).equals(args[1])) {

                 lines.set(i, newLine);
                 writer.write("");
             }
          }
       }
   break;

case "-d":
   try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
      for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {

         if (lines.get(i).substring(0, 8).trim().equals(args[1]) ||
             lines.get(i).substring(0, lines.get(i).indexOf(" ")).equals(args[1])) {

                 lines.remove(i);
                 writer.write("");
             }
          }
       }
    break;
  }

try (BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
   for (String line : lines) { 
       writer2.write(line);
       writer2.newLine();
   }
}
```

Но это решение не самое красивое, т.к. приходится создавать отдельный райтер для очистки содержимого файла и отдельный - для записи непосредственно из листа, и что совсем не радует - использовать копирование кода.

Comment: в джаве не силен: не надо промежуточных переменных, построчно читаешь файл - и тут же записываешь в новый или в этот же, наткнулся на нужную строчку - удалил или заменил. зачем плодить кучу стрингов и листов?

Comment: Конец строки это, \n, а не /n

Comment: Олексій Моренець, а в моем коде как обозначен перенос строки?..

Comment: slippyk, спасибо! Видимо я решил в духе индо-программирования налепить кучу кода, чтобы была куча кода...